# Adding ease-in and ease out in SVG hover stroke-width

Tags: svg, hover, onmouseover, onmouseout

I want to add ease-in-out over hover efect in svg map. I am creating the hover by stroke-width of the path. Is this possible at all?
Any other suggesting for creating such hovers in svg maps with easing are welcome. Thank you!

[Link to Codepen](http://codepen.io/RuDee/pen/ZOvoAA)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SVG Hover</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="56mm" width="56mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 200  200">
<g id="layer1" transform="translate(-277.14 -332.36)">
    <rect id="rect3336" height="200" width="200" y="332.36" x="277.14" fill="#cecece"/>
    <circle id="path4138" cx="380" cy="430" r="15"
        onmouseover="this.style.stroke = '#3f27dd'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 50; this.style['stroke-opacity'] = 0.7;"
        onmouseout="this.style.stroke = '#3f27dd'; this.style['stroke-width'] = 0;"/>
</g>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with JavaScript but I was able to do it with CSS. EDIT: I know but CSS looks cleaner.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgebi/q0dmd0k0/)

Here is my code:

```
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="56mm" width="56mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 200  200">
  <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-277.14 -332.36)">
    <rect id="rect3336" height="200" width="200" y="332.36" x="277.14" fill="#cecece"/>
    <circle id="path4138" cx="380" cy="430" r="15"
        />
  </g>
```

And CSS:

```
 #path4138 {
    transition: stroke-width 0.3s ease-in;
    stroke: #3f27dd;
    stroke-width: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0.7;
    fill: pink;
    pointer-events:all;
  }

  #path4138:hover {
    stroke-width: 50;
    fill: red;
    transition: stroke-width 0.3s ease-out;
  }
```